# Which version of @stripe/stripe-react-native module support react native 0.62.0 typscript template?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I tested some version to install module @stripe/stripe-react-native from 0.1.0 to 0.10.0 in my old project react-native 0.62.0 typescript but build was failed.but I test it in react native 0.64.4with  0.10.0 stripe version the build was  succeed .So i would to know there is a compatible module version that can be installed without update the project and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, i patched react-native-version  to  0.64.4  and I can install the version 0.10.0 and works fine with the gradle 6.8.3 using  compile version 31 .So it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [changelog](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#080---2022-04-27), `react-native@0.64.0` is needed since stripe-react-native `0.8.0`. You might want to try an older version (i.e., < 0.8.0) and see if it works for your project.

Comment: There is no version <0.10.0 works with me ,i patched it to 0.64.4 for make install the 0.10.0